# AppHarbor JabbR 500 Error

Tags: c#, appharbor, jabbr

I have gotten appharbor to build and deploy the solution but after I try to login it gives me a 500 error.   There is nothing in the error logs either and the tutorial doesn't seem to apply anymore.

Anyone know what could cause this?

EDIT:
Seems I am getting the following error when I pull down the build and run in IIS

Handler "Owin" has a bad module "ManagedPipelineHandler" in its module list

EDIT:
The earlier error is invalid and caused by my app pool not set to asp.net 4.0 but I do end up with the following error

Could not load file or assembly 'Microsoft.Owin.Host.SystemWeb' or one of its dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified.

EDIT:

Tried again with new repository and I still can't push to appharbor I don't think it has anything to do with the previous errors since it lets me register an account and lets me attempt to login then fails.

(Thanks for the change from signalr to jabbr tab, seems there was no jabbr tag and I can't make new ones due to score.)

Comment: You need to allow file write permissions